# How to set request cookies using selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, cookies, selenium, request

This is my source code

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(true);

driver.get("http://www.example.com");

Cookie cookie = new Cookie("key", "value");
driver.manage().addCookie(cookie);

Set<Cookie> allCookies = driver.manage().getCookies();
for (Cookie loadedCookie : allCookies) {
    System.out.println(String.format("%s -> %s", loadedCookie.getName(), loadedCookie.getValue()));
}
```

The request header to server doesn't contain the cookie.

If I change the position of the get() method after addCookie(),
the getCookies() will return empty.

I try it all day long.

no matter how I google it, i can't find any way to solve my problem

Hope somebody can help me!

I'll appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong reference to get the cookies, you should use

```
Set<Cookie> allCookies = driver.manage().getCookies();
```

instead, you are using `driver2` reference. where does `driver2` refer to?

**Update:** after your comment

Problem may be with your driver or the version of browser you use! Try doing it with another version of driver or different browser

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to modify this.
But the problem is still there :(